# recognize "it" subject in spaCY

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, spacy, recurrent-neural-network

Hi guys I recently discovered spaCY as an interesting way to recognize grammar in sentences, I tried with something easy and it works, but when I try to let it recognize the "it" subject in a short sentence it doesn't work very well, is there a way to improve the accuracy? the sentence I'm talking about is "do you like it?" where "it" is in this case the real subject. When I start the program spaCY recognizes "you" as a subject instead of "it".

What is a good way to avoid this kind of "errors"? here's the simple code:

```
import spacy

sentence = input('insert sentence: \n\n')
nlp = spacy.load('en')
sent = sentence
doc=nlp(sent)

sub_toks = [tok for tok in doc if (tok.dep_ == "nsubj") ]

print(sub_toks) 
print()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in fact not a Spacy problem but a grammar problem. In the sentence

> Do you like it?

The subject - as Spacy is telling you - is the word "you". The word "it" is the *object* of the verb "like". You may want to skim the [Wiki page for subject](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Subject_(grammar)) and the [Wiki page for object](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Object_(grammar)).

If you are looking for a sentence where "it" is the subject, Spacy can help you with that.

```
sent = nlp("it is very good")
for token in sent:
    print(token, token.dep_)

>> it nsubj
>> is ROOT
>> very advmod
>> good acomp
```

In this case, Spacy correctly reports that "it" is the nominal subject, and `token.dep` is equal to `'nsubj'`. Conversely, if what you really want is the direct object, then as you can see from this output:

```
sent = nlp("do you like it")
for token in sent:
    print(token, token.dep_)

>> do aux
>> you nsubj
>> like ROOT
>> it dobj
```

You should be looking for tokens where `token.dep_ == 'dobj'`. If you want indirect objects as well, you can also check for `'iobj'`. You can read more about the roles of these dependencies [here](http://universaldependencies.org/docs/en/dep/).

Comment: Did this end up solving your problem?

Comment: yeah it did, however I just encountered another problem, I slightly modified the code:

https://pastebin.com/F0LwQXZg

But how do I say to check the sentence "I will go to the mall" for a PRP + MD + NN and if there are matches to execute an instruction?

Comment: I'm going to need a little bit more information/context on what you're trying to do. If you post a new question, I (or someone else) can help.

Comment: basically i'm going to check for grammar in the sentences I give as input, if spaCY identifies PRP and MD and NN in a sentence then it will give me a text output "there is a prp, md and nn in the sentence". the problem is how can i tell spacy to check for PRP, MD and NN and then give me the desired text output?